# Is there a way to invoke the implementation of the generic class template from its specialization?

Tags: c++11, template-specialization

I have a template class

```
template<typename T>
class D : public B {...}
```

where B is a pure virtual interface implemented in class D. However, for one type T0, the implementation has additional data and an additional member function dealing with this data. Therefore, I have to specialize class D for this case:

```
template<>
class D<T0> : public B {...}
```

At the same time, the implementation of all other methods in this specialization is exectly the same as in the generic case, and I do not want to copy-paste it. The question is, how to call the generic implementation in the class D from the class `D<T0>`, if this at all possible.

PS. Of course, there is a solution with an intermediate derived class C, as suggested by @MaxLanghof and @Klaus. However, in this solution it is possible to instantiate the class `C<T0>`, which I do not want. This solution is a last resort that I will use if no other solution exists. Maybe in C++11/14 there are some modern constructs that can help in such cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> At the same time, the implementation of all other methods in this specialization is exectly the same as in the generic case.

So you should split the generic code to a common base class and derive from that new intermediate class for the general template and for the specialized one. It makes no sense to have a full code duplication on a template specialization.

As this common code is now a common base class, you simply can call that methods without any special syntax or tricks as they are common.

EDIT: Regarding the comments: How to protect to instantiate a object of intermediate class:

You have the keyword `protected` in C++ which makes it possible to protect access to the constructor.

Example:

```
class B{};
class T0;


template<typename T>
class C : public B /* all the non-specialized implementation of D */
{
    protected: C() {}
};


// Use the non-specialized implementation by default
template<typename T>
class D : public C<T> {};

// Add more functionality in the specialized case
template<>
class D<T0> : public C<T0> { /* your additional functionality */ };

int main()
{
    D<int> dint;
    D<T0>  dt0;

    C<int> Cint; // fails
    C<T0> Ct0;   // fails
}
```

Comment: I do prefer special syntax or tricks in order to do not allow instantiation of the class `C<T0>` for intermediate template class C.

Comment: Oh, this will help. Thanks a lot! I accept your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Add another layer.

```
template<typename T>
class C : public B { /* all the non-specialized implementation of D */ };
// (possibly hide this in some implementation detail namespace)

// Use the non-specialized implementation by default
template<typename T>
class D : public C {};

// Add more functionality in the specialized case
template<>
class D<T0> : public C { /* your additional functionality */ };
```

Comment: Thanks for the code example on my prosa answer. We should merge the answers :-)

Comment: @Klaus You have my permission to put the code into your answer, I'll remove mine afterwards :)

Comment: It feels the audience did the merge already in their brains :-)

Comment: @MaxLanghof, I thought in this direction, but found it not very good. The reason is that the user can instantiate the class `C<T0>`, which I wouldn't like to happen. On the other hand, I heard or read somewhere that C++11 offers some new constructs for such cases.

Comment: @Ilia That's why I mentioned "possibly hide this in some implementation detail namespace". Your users shall not use anything from there in the first place (just like they're not allowed to use any implementation details of `std` constructs).